# Adding a breadcrumb to my asp.net mvc web application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

A new requirement was issued to add a breadcrumb to our asp.net mvc we application, so I wrote the following code inside our layout view :-

```
  @{var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
                  var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

string coutput = "";

foreach (char letter in controller)
{
   if (Char.IsUpper(letter) && coutput.Length > 0)
   { coutput += " " + letter; }
   else
   { coutput += letter; }
}
string aoutput = "";

foreach (char letter in action)
{
    if (Char.IsUpper(letter) && aoutput.Length > 0)
    { aoutput += " " + letter; }
    else
    { aoutput += letter; }
}

                  }
            <div>

                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>

                        @Html.ActionLink(coutput, "", controller)

 <span class="divider">/</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         @Html.ActionLink(aoutput == "Index" ? "Home" : aoutput,action, controller)


                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The above is working well as it will split the controller name and action method name and build the vreadcrumb links. The advantage of my approach is that I re-use what I currently have (controller & action method names)to build the breadcrumb. But my question is whaeter defining the breadcrumb this way can create problems I am unaware of ?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to use ActionFilterAttribute.

Comment: You're asking us for a code review?

Comment: @Lin and how to use the ActionFilter in my case ?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic . no a code review , but rather an approach suggestion ..

Comment: @johnG, I updated an sample code, hope it'll give you a good idea.

Comment: Your question doesn't ask for suggestions, it's asking if there are problems with your approach. This is something that is generally addressed in a code review.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how big your project is, let's say you have 15 controllers and 60 view pages.
When you put above code to your main layout for a navigation bar, before the view page finishes loading, it needs to run the the code block in your view, even if some pages don't need it.
Also, keep view tight to the model, not the controller. It makes the view clean.

I suggest you to use ActionFilterAttribute. Because it's executed when you want to use it. Also for your case you can
create dynamic BreadCrumb view, and it's easy for reuse. Below is an sample code I wrote, I didn't test it, but it'll give you a good idea.

**ActionFilterAttribute**

```
 public class BreadcrumbAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            string coutput = Modifier(controllerName);
            string aoutput = Modifier(actionName);

            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.displayActionName = coutput;
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.displayControllerName = aoutput;
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ActionName = actionName;
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ControllerName = controllerName;
        }

        private string Modifier(string str)
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach (char letter in str)
            {
                if (Char.IsUpper(letter) && output.Length > 0)
                { output += " " + letter; }
                else
                { output += letter; }
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[Breadcrumb]
public class YourController : Controller
{
    //
}
```

**View**

```
<div>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink((string)@ViewBag.displayActionName, "", (string)@ViewBag.controllerName)
            <span class="divider">/</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink((string)@ViewBag.displayControllerName == "Index" ? "Home" : (string)@ViewBag.displayControllerName,(string)@ViewBag.ActionName, (string)@ViewBag.ControllerName)
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```